# How to disconnect all users in sql server except sa?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, maintenance-mode

I would like to disconnect all users from SQL Server except `sa`.

The need for this is:

I wrote a db maintenance utility for my ERP. Before running it I need to ask all users to logoff.
So somehow I would like to give them a message (through ERP) "disconnecting in 5 minutes, please save your work and logoff or you'll be kicked out" and then after 5 minutes run the command on the server that disconnects all people.
I want "sa" or anyway "1 specific user" not to be disconnected, since the db maintenance utilty will use that user for db connection.

I found this:

```
use master
alter database MyDatabase set offline with rollback immediate
```

but how to say "one specific user is an exception"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `single_user` instead of `offline`:

```
alter database [DatabaseName] set single_user with rollback immediate
```

The initial "single user" will be the one issuing the `alter database` command.  You could then proceed to only allow specific users to log on:

```
alter login [LoginName] disable
```

Comment: Perfect! single_user is what I was looking for.

Comment: How do I identify the single user?

Comment: @jtlz2 You can use [exec sp_who](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)